# Why files appear when doing git checkout my-branch

Tags: git

I would like to know why these files appear after doing `git checkout my-branch`.

```
$ git checkout develop
D       sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/Abstract.php
D       sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/AppIdentity.php
D       sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php
D       sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/ComputeEngine.php
D       sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/Exception.php
D       sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/LoginTicket.php
D       sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php
D       sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/Simple.php
Already on 'develop'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have deleted Some files but you didn't commit these changes.